# Ellipse by moving center of a parametric circle equation?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given that a parametric eq for a circle is given by :

$$x= r \cos \theta \\
y= r \sin \theta
$$

Is it possible to move the center of circle by a (periodic) function $f(r,\theta)$:

$$\begin{align}
x &= r \cos \theta + f(r,\theta)\\
y &= r \sin \theta
\end{align}$$ to obtain an ellipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually to define an ellipse in parametric equations, we just change the coefficients on the $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ terms.

$$x(t)=a\cos t$$
$$y(t)=b\sin t$$

So to answer your question, **yes**. $f(r,\theta)=n\cdot \cos\theta, n\in \mathbb R$. If we add any multiple of $r\cos$ to our $x$ part we obtain an ellipse.

$$x(t)=r\cos t+(n\cos t)\implies x(t)=(n+r)\cos t$$